# Pandas (merge/concat/join) multiple tables while putting results in one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

iam trying to merge multiple tables with pandas. but i cant figure out the right way to do what i want.

Table1:

```
     PV     NACHNAME  VORNAME      GEBURT      NATION
0    ID1   Nachname 1   Name 1  17.05.1994  TestNation
1    ID2   Nachname 2   Name 2  18.05.1994  TestNation
2    ID3   Nachname 3   Name 3  19.05.1994  TestNation
3    ID4   Nachname 4   Name 4  20.05.1994  TestNation
4    ID5   Nachname 5   Name 5  21.05.1994  TestNation
5    ID6   Nachname 6   Name 6  22.05.1994  TestNation
6    ID7   Nachname 7   Name 7  23.05.1994  TestNation
7    ID8   Nachname 8   Name 8  24.05.1994  TestNation
8    ID9   Nachname 9   Name 9  25.05.1994  TestNation
9   ID10  Nachname 10  Name 10  26.05.1994  TestNation
10  ID11  Nachname 11  Name 11  27.05.1994  TestNation
11  ID12  Nachname 12  Name 12  28.05.1994  TestNation
12  ID13  Nachname 13  Name 13  29.05.1994  TestNation
13  ID14  Nachname 14  Name 14  30.05.1994  TestNation
14  ID15  Nachname 15  Name 15  31.05.1994  TestNation
```

Table2:

```
     PV     FUNKTION    *NACHNAME *VORNAME
0    ID1   Funktion 1   Nachname 1   Name 1
1    ID1   Funktion 2   Nachname 1   Name 1
2    ID2   Funktion 3   Nachname 2   Name 2
3    ID3   Funktion 4   Nachname 3   Name 3
4    ID4   Funktion 5   Nachname 4   Name 4
5    ID4   Funktion 6   Nachname 4   Name 4
6    ID4   Funktion 7   Nachname 4   Name 4
7    ID4   Funktion 8   Nachname 4   Name 4
8    ID5   Funktion 9   Nachname 5   Name 5
9    ID6  Funktion 10   Nachname 6   Name 6
10   ID6  Funktion 11   Nachname 6   Name 6
11   ID7  Funktion 12   Nachname 7   Name 7
12   ID8  Funktion 13   Nachname 8   Name 8
13   ID9  Funktion 14   Nachname 9   Name 9
14  ID10  Funktion 15  Nachname 10  Name 10
15  ID10  Funktion 16  Nachname 10  Name 10
16  ID11  Funktion 17  Nachname 11  Name 11
17  ID12  Funktion 18  Nachname 12  Name 12
18  ID13  Funktion 19  Nachname 13  Name 13
19  ID14  Funktion 20  Nachname 14  Name 14
20  ID16   FUNKTION21  Nachname 16  Name 16
```

when i merge them with:
`pd.merge(df1,df2,on="PV",how="left")`

i get rid of the ID's that are in table two but not in table one.

the problem is i get lines like:

```
      PV     NACHNAME  VORNAME  ...     FUNKTION    *NACHNAME *VORNAME
0    ID1   Nachname 1   Name 1  ...   Funktion 1   Nachname 1   Name 1
1    ID1   Nachname 1   Name 1  ...   Funktion 2   Nachname 1   Name 1
```

but instead i'd like to get:

```
      PV     NACHNAME  VORNAME  ...     FUNKTION    FUNKTION    *NACHNAME  *VORNAME
0    ID1   Nachname 1   Name 1  ...   Funktion 1  Funktion 2  Nachname 1    Name 1
```

so i found this.

```
test = test.set_index('PV').groupby(level=0) \
    .apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)) \
    .unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)  # Thx @jezrael for sort reminder
test.columns = ['{}{}'.format(x[0], int(x[1]) + 1) for x in test.columns]
```

i understand the lower line of code adds the numbers to the top. but even without it i'd have the multiples of those lines.
but sadly it multiplies some of the fields i dont want to be multiplied. see here:

```
        FUNKTION1     GEBURT1    NACHNAME1     NATION1 VORNAME1    FUNKTION2   GEBURT2    NACHNAME2     NATION2 VORNAME2   FUNKTION3     GEBURT3  \
PV                                                                             
ID1    Funktion 1  17.05.1994   Nachname 1  TestNation   Name 1   Funktion 2  17.05.1994   Nachname 1  TestNation   Name 1         NaN         NaN
```

i mean i want the funktion part but i certainly dont want the name, geburt (birthday) and last name over and over and over.

can any one here help me?

€ just edited a typo

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you want to merge `df1` and `df2` and then "expand" the FUNKTIONs:

```
x = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="PV", how="left")

y = pd.concat(
    [
        x.drop_duplicates(subset="PV").set_index("PV"),
        x.groupby("PV")["FUNKTION"]
        .agg(list)
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .fillna("")
        .add_prefix("FUNKTION_"),
    ],
    axis=1,
).drop(columns="FUNKTION")
print(y)
```

Prints:

```
         NACHNAME  VORNAME      GEBURT      NATION    *NACHNAME *VORNAME   FUNKTION_0   FUNKTION_1  FUNKTION_2  FUNKTION_3
ID1    Nachname_1   Name_1  17.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_1   Name_1   Funktion_1   Funktion_2                        
ID2    Nachname_2   Name_2  18.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_2   Name_2   Funktion_3                                     
ID3    Nachname_3   Name_3  19.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_3   Name_3   Funktion_4                                     
ID4    Nachname_4   Name_4  20.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_4   Name_4   Funktion_5   Funktion_6  Funktion_7  Funktion_8
ID5    Nachname_5   Name_5  21.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_5   Name_5   Funktion_9                                     
ID6    Nachname_6   Name_6  22.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_6   Name_6  Funktion_10  Funktion_11                        
ID7    Nachname_7   Name_7  23.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_7   Name_7  Funktion_12                                     
ID8    Nachname_8   Name_8  24.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_8   Name_8  Funktion_13                                     
ID9    Nachname_9   Name_9  25.05.1994  TestNation   Nachname_9   Name_9  Funktion_14                                     
ID10  Nachname_10  Name_10  26.05.1994  TestNation  Nachname_10  Name_10  Funktion_15  Funktion_16                        
ID11  Nachname_11  Name_11  27.05.1994  TestNation  Nachname_11  Name_11  Funktion_17                                     
ID12  Nachname_12  Name_12  28.05.1994  TestNation  Nachname_12  Name_12  Funktion_18                                     
ID13  Nachname_13  Name_13  29.05.1994  TestNation  Nachname_13  Name_13  Funktion_19                                     
ID14  Nachname_14  Name_14  30.05.1994  TestNation  Nachname_14  Name_14  Funktion_20                                     
ID15  Nachname_15  Name_15  31.05.1994  TestNation          NaN      NaN
```

Comment: thank you so much, just one more question. if i have multiple fields like funktion and funktion_description and i want both in there, i figured out i can just put a list  in x.groupby("PV")[LIST] but that returns all values for Funktion in one list (and column) aswell as for funktion_description. how do i get every of the entries into a single col?